# How can I backup Linux server while it is running?

Tags: backup

I am using debian and ubuntu on my Linux VPS's. How can I backup my VPS's while they are running? And how can I restore them on any emergency?

Comment: "VPS" - so those are hosted using a virtualization technique like Xen. You can make instant backups if you've a LVM setup. You need to provide more details and this quesion is better suited for Serverfault.com.

Comment: But I cant make instant backups, it is not allowed on my service plan.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit what are those 'vps' and what is this 'service plan' you're talking about?
I wonder if actually you are not talking about some servers you own, but about virtual machines 'in a cloud' from some service provider.

Answer (score 3):

If you've got a good deal of time on your hands, and can leave your system online, you can do a remote rsync down to your system.

`rsync --recursive --progress user@host:sourcedir /path/to/save/backup/on/local/machine`

That should do what you want, but it'll take up a ton of space on your computer, because its literally a copy of the data on your VPS.  Note you might want to run this with the root user, if you want a total copy.  Also, this won't preserve the permissions, it'll just give you a copy of the files.

**About the Arguments Used Above**
In case you're curious as to what the arguments for the `rsync` directory:

`user@host:sourcedir`:  `user` means the username to use on the VPS (in this case, probably `root`).  `host` means the connection address you use for your VPS.  `sourcedir` means the directory you want to copy from.  In your case of a full VPS backup, you would probably want this to be `/`.

`/path/to/save/backup/on/local/machine/`:  You've got several different options with where you want to store your backup when its on your local drive.  In any case, you will want to make sure you can access this, so you would probably end up with something like `/home/user/VPSbackup/` where `user` is your local username on the local system (not on the VPS)

The `--recursive` argument will copy all files in every subdirectory from `sourcedir`.

The `--progress` argument will show you the progress of each file as its being downloaded (can be helpful in certain cases), because it can show you the time left to download each file (it'll flood your terminal screen, but that's not necessarily a bad thing if you want to see the progress).

**Most  importantly...**
***BE VERY VERY VERY CAREFUL!***
An rsync in which you switch the `user@host:sourcedir` and the `/path/to/save/` arguments will ***OVERWRITE*** your VPS with old data or no data.  This can also lead to you breaking things if you specify the wrong `/path/to/save/`.

Comment: This method does not copy system files that are in use on a running server, so it does not really address the original question.

Comment: Then their alternative is to have the host do an LVM snapshot, or have the host initiate some type of snapshot/backup system.  Otherwise, my statements here should work for most data, including some active data.

Comment: Can you list some other advance methods to backup live server? Full backup solutions.

Comment: @MountainX You have to adjust the sourcedir path to pull data from system directories, and change sourcedir to `/somepath` for system files.

Comment: @BigSack depends, are you on a VPS?  Or on your own system, etc.?  Full system backups on VPSes tend to be LVM backups or provider-created images or snapshots of the system after it's in shut-down mode.  If it's your own system you can just clone the drive, but that's a different question.  And I'm not stating cloud solutions because I consider most cloud solutions to be a vulnerability.

Comment: @ThomasW. I am on Dedicated Server with root acccess.

Comment: @BigSack honestly you should ask your question as a separate one.  The OP here was asking about a VPS, and a dedicated server is a separate thing and usually handled a bit differently.  I don't work with dedicated servers as I have my own hardware I colocate in a data center and pay for electricity and network access.  A full backup solution should be available through the provider for your dedicated server (assuming you're paying a provider for it), either as a snapshot or some other sort of backup solution through them.

Comment: Most host don't provide any backup or its only for internal use in case of disasters.

Comment: Some hosts do, but as I said you should ask a separate question as VPS backups and actual server backup methods kinda differ a little.

Answer (score 3):

The question specifies that the server should be backed up while it is running. The question does not say that the solution must be no-cost or open source. The comments indicate that the hosting provider probably doesn't support LVM. (That last assumption makes sense because Linode.com and SliceHost, for example, don't support LVM.)

If one is hosting with a VPS such as Linode.com, they offer an inexpensive backup solution. In my case, I pay an extra $5 per month for Linode's backup solution and it seems well worth it to me. It is very simple.

The only other option I know of that will meet the criteria stated above is R1Soft's Linux Hot Copy. It is free.

Here's their own advertising claims for the product. I have not used it yet, although I am seriously considering it. (I'm reading questions like this one as part of my research.) I have no affiliation with R1Soft and I don't have anything to gain by posting this information. I'm posting it because I do not know of any other solution that allows backing up a running server (including system files) other than LVM, btrfs, zfs, other COW file systems, and things that are generally not available on a VPS -- and R1Soft's Linux Hot Copy. It's the only other choice, afaik.

Hot Copy (hcp) - Free Universal Disk Snapshot Utility for Linux Servers

The R1Soft Hot Copy utility creates an instant point-in-time volume snapshot of any block device while the system is running without interrupting applications.  Works on almost any Linux block device.  It is like Volume Shadow Copy for Linux.

Hot Copy (hcp) - Universal Disk Snapshots for Linux

R1Soft Hot Copy (hcp) is the answer to taking online point-in-time disk and volume snapshots in Linux.  Use the hcp command line utility to take an instant snapshot of any mounted file system on almost any block device!

Windows administrators use Volume Shadow Copy Service (VSS).  On Linux servers before Hot Copy nothing equivalent existed.  R1Soft created Hot Copy so every Linux server has a universal disk snapshot that is fast and easy to use.

Why Hot Copy is the Answer to Linux Disk and Volume Snapshots

```
Works on any server-based file system or block device
Install without rebooting
Eliminates LVM pre-requisite
Requires no pre-allocation or pre-configuration of storage
Uses existing free space on your disk to maintain snapshots
Outstanding performance compared to LVM snapshots
Works on most High-Availability and Shared Storage
Specialized performance awareness for: Ext2, Ext3, Ext4, and Reiserfs3
Snapshots are readable and writable
Keep multiple snapshots of each disk or volume
```

What you Can Do With Hot Copy

```
Add point-in-time open file backups to your existing backup scripts for free e.g. tar and rsync
Check your disk for errors with fsck without rebooting and without unmounting your file system!
Test scripts and programs in an instant snapshot of your live environment before you use them on real data
Keep instantly recoverable snapshots available by taking periodic snapshots via cron
```

Answer (score 1):

rsnapshot is a filesystem snapshot utility for making backups of local and remote systems

Comment: Could you dwell a bit more in how could I use them?

Answer (score 0):

You CAN move live system to LVM.

Install necessary kernel modules and load them (or compile kernel with appropriate config and reboot VDS).

After that you can move root to LVM, change root FS on live system without reboot. It is possible with "pivot_root" and temporary moving root fs to another place (to RAM, for example).

But be carefully, it's dangerous.

Comment: If it's a VPS through a VPS provider, you can't, because the VPS image has to be set up as such by the provider.

Answer (score -1):

Take an LVM snapshot and back it up with dump.

Comment: Read the comments dude, he cant make the backups:  But I cant make instant backups, it is not allowed on my service plan. – Baran

Comment: @EvilPhoenix what does a service plan have to do with anything?  It's your server, you have root access, you can back up what you damn well please.  They just won't do it automagically for you outside of the vm.

Comment: "Take an LVM snapshot" he cant do that, he doesnt have access to that service, from how I interpret his question and comments.

Comment: @EvilPhoenix if he has root he does.  AFAICS, the "service" that is offered and he does not have in his plan is for the admins to make a snapshot on the real hardware outside of his virtual machine.  What goes on inside the vm is up to him.

Comment: @psusi: Could it be that the system isnt set up in LVM format?  Or could it possibly be that he doesnt know how?

Comment: @EvilPhoenix yes, you do need to have LVM set up in the first place to take a snapshot, which might require a reinstall if you didn't set it up in the first place.

Comment: @psusi: In which case, basing on information the user provided, I'm going to assume he chose a VPS plan which put his/her VPS onto a non-LVM system, hence no access to the LVM snapshot/backup system.

Comment: @psusi Actually, it's true you can't.

Comment: @LordofTime, if he has root access he can always set up LVM himself.  It requires no help or knowledge from the hosting company.

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS, can't what?